# Why CodeIgniter-Bootstrap is only loading in frontepage.php but not in my view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

When I go to :

codeigniter/index.php
Bootstrap styles load fine. Actually is the content from

codeigniter/application/views/frontpage.php :

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="hero-unit">
      <h2>CodeIgniter Bootstrap</h2>
      <p>CodeIgniter Bootstrap kick starts the development process of the web development process by including Twitter Bootstrap into CodeIgniter. It also includes certain libraries such as AWS and Facebook in-case you are developing applications requiring those SDKs. So stop writing the same code over again and start working on your idea.</p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="https://github.com/sjlu/CodeIgniter-Bootstrap">View on Github</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I copy-paste the same content into my own file

```
codeigniter/application/views/index.php
```

It does not load correctly. My controller looks like this:

```
<?php

class Cart extends CI_Controller {  

    function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('cart_model'); // Load our cart model for our entire class
    }

    function index()
    {
        $data['products'] = $this->cart_model->retrieve_products(); // Retrieve an array with all products
        $data['content'] = 'products'; // Select our view file that will display our products
        $this->load->view('index', $data); // Display the page with the above defined content
    }

}
/* End of file cart.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/cart.php */
```

and the frontpage controller is:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) die();
class Frontpage extends Main_Controller {

   public function index()
    {
      $this->load->view('include/header');
      $this->load->view('frontpage');
      $this->load->view('include/footer');
    }

}

/* End of file frontpage.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/frontpage.php */
```

Comment: We need to see your controller that calls for index and frontpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by including header and footer in the index() method of controller:

```
function index()
{
    $data['products'] = $this->cart_model->retrieve_products(); // Retrieve an array with all products      
    $data['content'] = 'products'; // Select our view file that will display our products

    $this->load->view('include/header');
    $this->load->view('index', $data); // Display the page with the above defined content
    $this->load->view('include/footer');

}
```

include/header.php adds all the bootstrap stuff

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta name="description" content="">
   <meta name="keywords" content="">
   <meta name="author" content="">

   <title>Car application</title>

   <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.1.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/custom.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">

   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/1.2.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/custom.js') ?>"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use base_url() like

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```